Convert SQL Cursor to Spark Dataframe
I have this below SQL Stored procedure which i am trying to convert into Spark Dataframe. Provided that i have the Data in my Notebook. how can i convert this into the spark dataframe, i am not sure particularly where the If Conditions are applied on how to convert these into dataframe logic and find and update matching records.
Below is the code that i need help with. This is comparing each row of a self row in a cursor to all other rows.
How can i compare each row of a dataframe to all other rows for the below logic and update the rows accordingly.
BEGIN
 
   IF ((@CustomerRef = @NCustomerRef) AND (@CompCode = 
  @NCompCode)
        AND ((@StartDate <= ISNULL(@NEndDate, 
@NProposedEndDate)) AND (ISNULL(@EndDate, @ProposedEndDate) >= 
@NStartDate))
        )
    BEGIN
      SELECT @OldValue = CASE (@ComplaintStatusRefCode) WHEN 
  ‘LODGED’ THEN 4 WHEN 'FINISHED' THEN 3 WHEN 'REPORTED' THEN 
  2 ELSE 1 END
      SELECT @NewValue = CASE (@NComplaintStatusRefCode) WHEN 
‘LODGED’ THEN 4 WHEN 'FINISHED' THEN 3 WHEN 'REPORTED' THEN 2 
 ELSE 1 END
      IF (@OldValue = @NewValue)
      BEGIN
         IF (@ActualLength > @NActualLength) SET @OldValue = 
 @OldValue + 1 ELSE SET @NewValue = @NewValue + 1
      END
      IF (@StartDate > @NStartDate)
      BEGIN
          SET @StartDate =  @NStartDate
          SET @ProposedStartDate = @NProposedStartDate
      END
      IF (ISNULL(@NEndDate, @NProposedEndDate) > 
 ISNULL(@EndDate, @ProposedEndDate))
      BEGIN
         SET @EndDate =  @NEndDate
         SET @ProposedEndDate = @NProposedEndDate
      END
      SET @CLength = DateDiff(Week, @ProposedStartDate, 
 @ProposedEndDate)
      SET @ActualLength = DateDiff(Week, @StartDate, 
 ISNULL(@EndDate, @ProposedEndDate))
      SET @Calc_10pc = CASE WHEN (@ActualLength < 
 ((@CLength/10)+0.1)) THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END
      SET @Cse_10pc =  CASE WHEN (@ActualLength < 
((@TotalWeeks/10)+0.1)) THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END
 
      IF (@OldValue > @NewValue)
      BEGIN
         /* Use the older Complaints as the main */
         SET @MRule = @MRule + @Step + ' ' + @NMRule
         SET @MValue  = @MValue + ',' + @NMValue
      END
      ELSE
      BEGIN
         /* Use the newer Complaints as the main */
         SET @CustomerRef =  @NCustomerRef
         SET @CustomerId = @NCustomerId
         SET @ComplaintCode = @NComplaintCode
         SET @ComplaintStatusRefCode= @NComplaintStatusRefCode
         SET @SCTypeRefCode = @NSCTypeRefCode
         SET @PrvisionerId = @NPrvisionerId
         SET @ProvisionCode =  @NProvisionCode
         SET @OrgCode = @NOrgCode
         SET @SectorCode = @NSectorCode
         SET @CmpId = @NCmpId
         SET @CompCode = @NCompCode
         SET @TotalWeeks = @NTotalWeeks
         SET @LvlRefCode = @NLvlRefCode
         SET @FSRefCode = @NFSRefCode
         SET @DualComp = @NDualComp
         SET @FSCode1 = @NFSCode1
         SET @FSCode2 = @NFSCode2
         SET @NRFCode = @NNRFCode
         SET @PrvComments = @NPrvComments
         SET @MRule = @NMRule + @Step + ' ' + @MRule
         SET @MValue = @NMValue + ',' + @MValue
      END
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
     Insert Record
   END


Please simplify your example by removing the code that are not needed to demonstrate the problem.

Removed the code that was not necessary. I really need help with the if conditions in the cursor to convert to spark df. and update all rows based upon the matches.

Let us what you have tried to implement already
